# Acumatica How to iterate through files attached to Project?

Tags: acumatica

I want to access all files attached to the current project. Im not able to find any files using the PXSelect statement below.

My Code

```
public PXSelect<UploadFile, Where<UploadFile.name, Like<Current<PMProject.contractCD>>>> Files;


string files = "";
        foreach (UploadFile f in Files.Select())
        {
            files += "\n"+f.FileID;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static `GetFileNotes` method of the **PXNoteAttribute** returns the list of identifiers of files attached to a record. Below is a code snippet showing how to retrieve all files attached to the current project:

```
public class ProjectEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
{
    public PXAction<PMProject> GetFiles;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Files")]
    protected void getFiles()
    {
        var projectCache = Base.Caches[typeof(PMProject)];
        Guid[] files = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(projectCache, projectCache.Current);
        foreach (Guid fileID in files)
        {
            var fm = new PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance();
            PX.SM.FileInfo fi = fm.GetFileWithNoData(fileID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ruslan!

Comment: If I wanted to access the public document link how would I? fi.  doesn't have a value.

Comment: ~/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID=[UID] <- Worked for me

Comment: `ControlHelper.GetAttachedFileUrl(null, fileID.ToString())` should return the public document link